# onprepareoptionsmenu was called by default

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I got a need to change the menu items dynamically during a click event of menu items.

So I implemented **onOptionsItemSelected** in an activity.

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and i'm calling **invalidateOptionsMenu** in the **onOptionsItemSelected** method which inturn should call the **onPrepareOptionsMenu**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
            case R.id.action_group: {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                break;
            }
               }
}
```

Also, I am trying to remove one item from menu in onPrepareOptionsMenu method.

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


        Log.d(TAG,"In onPrepareOptionsMenu");
        menu.removeItem(R.id.action_group);
        Log.d(TAG,"Group icon is removed");

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

The problem is, item is deleted during the launch of activity rather than wait until corresponding menu item is clicked.

Can someone tell what the problem is.. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)` gets called anyway, anytime your menu needs to be shown or reloaded. That includes calls coming from `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, but also from the Activity being created.

You could, for example, check for a boolean state before actually removing the item.

```
public boolean mRemoveItem;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
switch (id){
        case R.id.action_group: {
            mRemoveItem = true;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            break;
            }
           }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (mRemoveItem) {
    menu.removeItem(R.id.action_group);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

According to your needs, you will need to set `mRemoveItem` back to `false` at some point in your code.